# How to transfer horizontal data to vertical between sheets

Tags: excel

I am trying to transfer data from Sheet 2, where it is in cell range D70:AC70 (26 cells, horizontally) to sheet 1 in cell range L12:L37 (26 cells, vertically).

I am making a template so I need a formula that I can click and drag down.

I have tried transpose which does not work as this needs to cell reference for the template. I have tried OFFSET and INDEX Function but it has not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Index` will do it, something like this

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$70:$70,1,COLUMN(Sheet2!$D$70)+ROW()-ROW($L$12))
               ^                       ^               ^
               |                       |               |
Reference to whole source row          |               |
                Reference to first cell in             |
                source row to copy                     |
                                 Reference to first cell in destination column
```

Copy down as far as needed

Comment: Ahh. Amazing. Thank you so much.